# How to rebuild a specific key of a Hashtable every time its called?

Tags: powershell

I find PowerShell growing on me and consequently I am spending allot of time on the terminal.
I have many hash tables in my profile, for various uses but mostly to keep common data right under my fingers.

I have one such Hashtable here:

```
$SYS = [Ordered]@{
    Posh = "C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe"
    ReflectLogs = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\All Users\Macrium\Reflect" -Filter *.html*
    ShareXUploadHistory = Convertfrom-Json -Inputobject (Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\...\Documents\Sharex\History.Json")
    }
```

The `ShareXUploadHistory` key reads from a file that is constantly changing, I would like to rebuild the key, so that every time I call `$SYS.ShareXUploadHistory` the json data will be based on the latest state of the file `History.Json` NOT when my `$Profile` was loaded.

I tried the following but the key is not updated when I call `$SYS.ShareXUploadHistory`:

```
$SYS = [Ordered]@{
    Posh = "C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe"
    ReflectLogs = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\All Users\Macrium\Reflect" -Filter *.html*
    ShareXUploadHistory = . {Convertfrom-Json -Inputobject (Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\...\Documents\Sharex\History.Json")}
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it can be adding it as [`PSScriptProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psscriptproperty?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0), then each time you invoke the member (`$SYS.ShareXUploadHistory`) it would be re-evaluated. Downside is, since this is an `ordered` dictionary and not a `pscustomobject` you wouldn't see it as a Key.

```bash
$SYS = [ordered]@{
   Posh        = 'C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe'
   ReflectLogs = Get-ChildItem -Path 'path\to\stuff' -Filter *.html*
}

$SYS.PSObject.Members.Add([psscriptproperty]::new(
   'ShareXUploadHistory',
   { Get-Content 'path\to\Sharex\History.Json' -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json }))

$SYS
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution I came up with involves wrapping the code assigned to the key in `{}` and when calling that specific key, to prefix it with a `.` followed by a space, not as prompt as Santiago's answer but it works:

```
    $SYS = [Ordered]@{
        Posh = "C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe"
        ReflectLogs = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\All Users\Macrium\Reflect" -Filter *.html*
        ShareXUploadHistory = {Get-Content -Path "c:\temp\History.Json" | ConvertFrom-Json}
        }
```

and then calling it with:

```
 . $sys.ShareXUploadHistory
```